# UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:"

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been trying to solve an issue related to SQLALCHEMY in Flask as my db is not getting created even though I set the SQLACHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'".

In the warning it says the 'sqlite:///:memory:'. When db.create_all() is call test.sql file is not created and also in the UI I see errors as mentioned bellow:

Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' memberpylint(no-member) and 3 others

Please help in resolving this issue and generating the db and SQL file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime


#Initializing database
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#Creating model
class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    completed = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id
        

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: The code example you have posted doesn't raise that warning. It occurs when the `SQLAlchemy` instance is created before the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` has been configured, but that is not the case in your example. I've run your snippet locally and can confirm that the warning isn't raised and the `test.db` file is created. Are you sure you are running the code that you think you are?

Comment: I should mention that I had to add `db.create_all()` before `app.run(...)` to get the database to create.